# How to prove euler formula for surface meshes with disk or sphere topology?

Tags: geometry

For disk topology the euler formula is V - E + F = 1, for sphere it is V - E + F = 2. Is there a simple and elegant way to prove these?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to prove it. I bet if you type $$\rm Euler\ formula\ for\ maps$$ into your favorite search engine, many proofs will come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By induction:

- Start with a triangle (or square or however your mesh is build up) and verify that $V+F-E=1$ (e.g. triangle: $3-1-3=1$)
- Add another point $V\to V+1$ to get another triangle, means 2 more edges  $E\to E+2$ and one more face $F\to F+1$. In total $V+F-E\to (V+1)+ (F+1) - (E-2)=V+F-E $
- Or add an edge connecting to vertices. Then $E\to E+1$ and $F\to F+1$ and in total $V+F-E \to V+(F+1)-(E-1)=V+F-E$